# Traduzindo comando copy do CMD para o Copy-Item do PowerShell

Tags: cmd, concatenação-de-string, powershell

Estou tentando traduzir um comando do **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** para o **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** mas não estou conseguindo.

Recebo vários arquivos.txt durante o mês, coloco todos na mesma pasta, alguns possuem termos específicos no nome que uso para selecionar e concatenar os semelhantes.

Mas no final do mês, concateno todos em um único arquivo para trabalhar com todos de uma única vez, esse processo de concatenação no CMD eu efetuava da seguinte forma:

**’copy *abobrinha*.txt TodasAbobrinhas.txt’**

Traduzindo:

- copy - comando que efetua a cópia;
- *abobrinha*.txt - seleciona todos os arquivos com o termo "abobrinha" no nome para concatenar;
  TodasAbobrinhas.txt - arquivo final com todos os arquivos concatenados.

Ao tentar usar esse comando no **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**  ele executa mas não gera o arquivo esperado e também não dá nenhuma mensagem de erro.

Alguém consegue me dar uma dica para fazer esse processo no **PowerShell**?

Já agradeço a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim no PowerShell

```
copy-item *abobrinha*.txt -destination todasabobrinhas.txt
```

Comment: Não funciona, ele executa o comando mas não aparece nenhum resultado...

Comment: mas vendo aqui, acho que o caminho é esse, ele gera o arquivo mas com o conteúdo de apenas um arquivo...

Answer (score 4):

[image: Mostrando a utilização do script]
Como o seu objetivo é copiar o conteúdo dos arquivos **`*abobrinha*.txt`** já concatenando em outro arquivo com nome **TodasAbobrinhas.txt**, acredito que os passos para alcançar seu objetivo seja:

1. Pega o conteúdo do arquivos filtrando **`TodasAbobrinhas.txt`** que sera gerada com o conteúdo do primeiro, assim passa a existir durante execução, mas é evitado:

   ```bat
   Get-ChildItem *abobrinha*.txt -Exclude TodasAbobrinhas.txt
   ```
2. Pega o conteúdo de cada **item/arquivo** mantendo o códigos de caracteres:

   ```bat
   Foreach-Object {Get-Content $_ -Raw}
   ```
3. Move os respectivos conteúdos dos arquivos para o arquivo de saída apontado:

   ```bat
   Out-File TodasAbobrinhas.txt
   ```

---

```bat
 Get-ChildItem *abobrinha*.txt -Exclude TodasAbobrinhas.txt|Foreach-Object {Get-Content $_ -Raw}| Out-File TodasAbobrinhas.txt
```

- Ou uma segunda opção portada para seu caso de postagem **[`SO/EN Q:8749929`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695/gishu)** mais simples:

```bat
cat *abobrinha*.txt -E TodasAbobrinhas.txt | sc TodasAbobrinhas.txt
```

- **Obs1.: `-E` == `-Exclude` : é o mesmo**
- **Obs2.:** Notas do **Operador [`SO/EN @Gishu`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695/gishu)**:

> **Nota 1:** O **`cat`** é um **alias** para **`Get-Content`**, e **`sc`** é um **alias** para o **`Set-Content`**.
>
> **Nota 2:** A saída para um arquivo com **`>`** não preserva a **codificação de caracteres!** É por isso que o uso de **`Set-Content (sc)`** é recomendado.